# Laravel dompdf errors

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I'm using Laravel to build an web application. I want to create an PDF document, therefore I use the DOMPDF class by BarryVDH. (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/tree/0.4)

In my view, when I use an CSS asset, I get the following error:

```
file_put_contents(XXXX/app/storage/fonts/6fb68711b6675ac0a3fd0da8c654f06d.ttf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone knows how I can fix this?

Comment: Likely your CSS is referencing a font using the `@font-face` declaration causing dompdf to fetch the font. The location from the error looks to be where your larval plugin wants to store the font file. That directory should exist and the user executing dompdf (e.g. the web server) should have read/write access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitly a problem with the destination folder path.

change your path

```
XXXX/app/storage/fonts/
```

or check maybe u don't have that directory or  don't have file in that directory!

Comment: It doesn't exist. Do I have to create it and put the ttf font files in there?

Comment: yes u need to have ttf or otf font in your directory, because u use file_put_contents function which require file, file_put_contents function write a string to a file, This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.

Comment: Yes, I already knew that, but the problem is: I don't even have a font file. Apparently I fixed it by don't using Bootstrap...

Comment: also u can use fonts with css... dont be afraid to give me some reputation points

Comment: It's not really a solution. But thumbs up is given :-)

Comment: Hello all,

I am using dompdf for creating pdf file for my bootstrap based view, but it keeps on loading and nothing actually loads up. I have tried it with simple html and then it geneartes pdf nicely. But my view for invoice is designed in bootstrap which contains custom fonts that seems to be creating problems. I have created fonts directory in storage folder but still not working. Can any one help me!